# Difference between python pygir-ctypes and gi.repository

Tags: python, windows, gtk3, activestate, gobject-introspection

I don't understand the difference and requirements of 2 python gtk3 packages.

one is the activestate **pygir-ctypes** package installed by pypm and the other one is the standard linux (I use Ubuntu) python **gobject-introspection**.

The documentation on gobject-introspection at https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html is pretty good if you run linux based OS, but on Windows the alternative seems to be activestate's pygir-ctypes implementations, but documentation is limited.

I have a small GUI which uses GTK3 python gobject-introspection, starting with

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

the pygir-ctypes starts with

```
from gir import Gtk
```

My assumption is at the moment it is the same but the packages have different requirements in regard to its installation. On Windows there are several comments on the web around only limited support for Python GTK3 (via gobject-introspection) support and nothing is really usable at this moment, but this pygir-ctypes looks promising. I would like to run my GUI on Windows.

Can someone explain the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I am not familiar with pygir-ctypes but PyGObject is quite usable on Windows: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/